# program doesn't open but there is no compile error

Tags: android

Can you guys have a look at this please? MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.mi47.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridView;

        gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gridView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (parent.getId()==R.id.grid_view){
            switch(position){
                case 0:{
                    startActivity(new Intent(this,DotDraw.class));
                    break;
                }
                case 1:{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
                case 2:{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
                case 3:{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
                case 4:{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
                case 5:{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click Inside" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="72dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="48dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

compiles without any warning/error. the DotDraw class is just a new page im opening, nothing important. any idea why program keeps closing?

LOGCAT:
03-15 18:41:12.567 8655-8655/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.mi47.test, PID: 8655
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mi47.test/com.mi47.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
                                                     at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:800)
                                                     at com.mi47.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: post the logcat error during the crash

Comment: Paste the lgcat error here and also show the dotdraw class thanks

Comment: Note that the compiler doesn't (can't!) tell you if your program is correct.  It can only tell you errors that make it so bad it can't process it.  "it compiles" isn't much of an indicator of correctness at all.

Comment: posted logcat as asked. dotdraw class is completely empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clearly mentioned in the log cat,

```
Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
```

You are setting `OnClickListener` in the `GridView` which is a `AdapterView`. This operation is not allowed.

**You should be using `OnItemClickListener` instead** of that which will give you callbacks when a particular item is clicked on the GridView.

Comment: yeah, i understand now :( caffeine is a hell of a drug.... jittery me typing wrong stuff.

Comment: haha,coffee is life, man, but you have to take care of the quantity

Comment: But after all, did you solve your problem? @TahirIslam

Comment: yup, i did. i noticed the logcat after i posted it here haha @Duan Bressan

Comment: If this answer helps you, please consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

`gridView.setOnClickListener(this);`

this is the problem

you need to use for `Gridview` adapter:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```